# "A few days need to wear on for her in order to feel better"

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I am not sure if this sentence is correct.
Would it be better to say "[...] in order for her to feel better" ?

Comment: What does "A few days ***need to wear on***" mean? I'm not familiar with that phrase. What does "wear on" have to do with her feeling better? Thanks.

Comment: A few days need to wear on -> A few days need to pass

Comment: Can you give us some context as to where you whould use this phrase?

Comment: " After she had had this accident, a lot of days needed to wear on in order for her to feel better "

Comment: @ILoveChess, you need to add these details to your question, because right now, we can't really tell what you're asking. (In any question where you ask "is this sentence correct", you need to specify which part you're asking about, what you believe/want the sentence to mean, and why you think it might not be correct.)

Comment: In colloquial U.S. English, we might say something like "She needs to take it easy for a few days so she can start to feel batter."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"She needs more time to heal."** (Less specific but more concise.) Or,

**"She still needs a few days in order to feel better."** (Closer to your original.) Or,

**"A few more days need to wear on in order for her to feel better."** (Closest to original.)